# Near Protocol, Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, near

When I run the command `yarn build:release` i get the error "command not found: asb"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHMMN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first run `yarn` after that try `yarn build:release`